# Issues with updating the State - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having issues in updating the state values, I'm rendering a external component using Map, and hence not able to access **this**. So on click of the component I'm not able to call the handleClick function to update the state values..

Here is the state :

```
this.state = {
   attributes : {
       hours : {

       },
       cost : 0,
       amenities : defaultAmenities
   },
   primary_category : "General"
}
```

Where **defaultAmenities** is a external file with large javascript object.

The render function :

```
render() {
    let basicAmenities, extendedAmenities
    let basicAmenitiesList = [], extendedAmenitiesList = []

    //Wrong way of storing this
    let _this = this;
}

... More Logics / Switch Cases ...

let amenitiesList = basicAmenitiesList.map(function(item, index){
    return <Attribute key={index} name={item.amenity_id} type={item.title} icon={item.icon} selected={item.isSelected} value="" onClick={_this.handleClick.bind(_this)}/>
})
```

And the attribute component

```
<div className="attribute-grid" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
     ...
</div>
```

Handle click is a function to setState on click of Attribute.

```
handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

On click of the attribute, I need to update the state. The result of console log is attached below. I need to target the input values, but since it return the entire div, how do i get the values of name/value/placeholder?

```html
<div class="attribute-grid-block" data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0"><div class="attribute-grid-img" data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0.0"><img src="petsIcon" data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0.0.0"></div><div class="attribute-grid-info" data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0.1"><h6 data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0.1.0">Pets</h6><input type="text" name="pets" placeholder="NO INFO FOUND" value="" disabled="" data-reactid=".0.2.0.3.0.1.$0.0.1.1"></div></div>
```

Comment: What values do you want on click?

Comment: @DavinTryon The value from the input [name, value, disabled]

Comment: And also, setting _this = this is a right way of doing it?

Comment: No, I don't think that is the best way.  Just bind the mapping function instead (or use arrow functions).

Comment: You need to do more than just defer to `props.onClick` in `<div className="attribute-grid" onClick={this.props.onClick}>`.  You need to do something inside the `Attribute` component so that the on its `onClick` the correct values are sent as args.

Answer (score 0):

you can get what you need from the target. but you need to set the `onClick` on the element that you want it to be the target and then you will have it:

```
handleClick(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const placeholder = e.target.placeholder;
    console.log(placeholder);
}
```

if you want to set the `onClick` elsewhere you will need to send the values you want, so inside `Attribute` component you will have a function that will be invoke on click and call the `this.props.onClick({ name: '', value: ''});`

if you need to use `this` inside this function, and you are using react with classes. you can write this:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(this);
}
```